# how to integrate google reCAPTCHA in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter 2.4. I have to use google recaptcha in ony of my project.Below is my code.

```
// field validation
$this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_challenge_field', 'Captcha Code', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_checkCaptcha');
```

The call back function is :

```
    function checkCaptcha($captcha){
    $resp = $this->recaptcha->recaptcha_check_answer ( $this->input->ip_address(), $this->input->post('recaptcha_challenge_field',true), $this->input->post('recaptcha_response_field',true));

    if($resp->is_valid)
    {
        return true;
        }

    else 
    {
         $this->form_validation->set_message('checkCaptcha', 'Sorry Invalid captcha code');
         return false;
        }

    }
```

But I am getting this error:

```
  A PHP Error was encountered

  Severity: Notice

  Message: Trying to get property of non-object

 Filename: controllers/offer.php

 Line Number: 59
```

Please help me where I am going wrong .

Thanks.

Comment: Have you included the class for recaptcha? Which line is 59?

Comment: I have included the library in the constructer as
$this->load->library('recaptcha');

Comment: The line no 59 is
 if($resp->is_valid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated my code and it works for me now. In the captcha library I have made the is_valid property public and then I replaced

```
if($resp->is_valid)
```

with

```
if($this->recaptcha->is_valid)
```

Now it works for me.

Thanks for all who responed my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function captcha_verify(){
    $form_response = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

    $secretkey = "6LeBGG0UAAAAAEzWMaT0sOjPxcbNwQe7TiWWAknQ";

    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$secretkey."&response=".$form_response."&remoteip=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

    $data = json_decode($response);
    print_r($data);

    if (isset($data->success) && $data->success=="true") {
        echo "Successfully Passed through captcha";
    }
    else{
        echo "Please Fill captcha";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please avoid answer with code only. Add some explanations about your solution .

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your private key in here too as the first parameter:

```
$resp = $this->recaptcha->recaptcha_check_answer ($private_key,  $this->input->ip_address(), $this->input->post('recaptcha_challenge_field',true), $this->input->post('recaptcha_response_field',true));
echo "<pre>";print_r($resp);die; #check the response array.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working in **codeigniter 3.1.5**. I have to use this code but not work for  me but this code work for me in google recaptcha in google recaptcha in codeigniter 3.1.5.

this is my code for **google recaptcha in codeigniter**

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="ADD_YOUR_GOOGLE_SITE_KEY_HERE"></div>
```

function of google validate captcha

```
function google_validate_captcha() {
    $google_captcha = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
    $google_response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=your secret key here &response=" . $google_captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if ($google_response . 'success' == false) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://www.onlinecode.org/integrate-google-recaptcha-codeigniter-validation/) :: http://www.onlinecode.org/integrate-google-recaptcha-codeigniter-validation/